# Delphi App Upgrade from Delphi 10 Seattle to Delphi 13.3.3 Rio - SQL Server Db Column with Space(s) not working in ClientDataSet and SimpleDataSet

Tags: delphi

We are upgrading our Working Delphi App from Delphi 10 Seattle to Delphi 13.3.3 Rio - SQL Server Db Column with Space(s)

The code associated with this issue works as intended in Delphi 10 Seattle and SQLServer. 
The problem is that the Column "Image Type" has a space in its name.
I am looking to solve the space in column names for ClientDataSet and SimpleDataSet 
This applies to other table that we have. I know that a parameterized SQL would work as a workaround.

The following Insert SQL Execute statements work as intended.

```
INSERT INTO tblImages ("Line","Image Type","Image") VALUES ('1','jpg','imageBlobValue')
```

or

```
INSERT INTO tblImages ([Line],[Image Type],[Image]) VALUES ('1','jpg','imageBlobValue')
```

The following Insert via ClientDataSet Does not

```
//Query
SQLQueryInsert.Cose;
SQLQueryInsert.SQL:='SELECT "Line","Image Type","Image" FROM tblImages';//Oracle & Other SQLs
SQLQueryInsert.SQL:='SELECT  [Line],[Image Type],[Image] from tblImages';//SQLServer
SQLQueryInsert.Open;
//Set Non parameterized values
//DataSet
ClientDataSettblImages.Close;
ClientDataSettblImages.Open;
ClientDataSettblImages.Insert;
ClientDataSettblImages['Line']:='1';
ClientDataSettblImages['Image Type']:='jpg';
ClientDataSettblImages['Image']:='imageBlobValue';
//Apply Updates
ClientDataSettblImages.Post;
If ClientDataSettblImages.ChangeCount > 0 then
  Begin
      ClientDataSettblImages.ApplyUpdates(-1);
End
```

If I look at the text output of SQLMonitor I can see the following:

```
Error: SQL State: 1, SQL Error Code: 156, Level: 15, Procedure: , Line: 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Type'.
```

ClientDataSet & SimpleDataSet have the same issue. I can see that the problem is the column with the space called "Image Type". The insert via the ClientDataSet works fine without the column "Image Type".
This either looks like a ClientDataSet bug or I'm missing a simple detail somewhere.

Comment: I wonder how you get something like `ClientDataSettblImages["Line"]:='1';` compile in Delphi.

Comment: That was a typo when I transcribed it...ClientDataSettblImages["Line"]:='1'; I corrected it in this post to ClientDataSettblImages['Line']:='1';

Comment: How do you connect the ClientDataSet to the SQL server?

Comment: Connect ClientDataSet (TDatasetProvider->TSQLQuery->TSQLConnection ) via TSQLConnection, I set the Server, Database and Login Parameters only.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer is to add the following Parameter to SQLConnection:        UseQuoteChar=True. The Application is now working as intended.